# Is there an EU right to know the cost of checked in luggage?

Tags: luggage, check-in, klm

I’m flying from U.K. to Japan with connection in Netherlands with KLM airline. I’ve been told I have to ask at the check in counter to know the price of a checked in luggage (I don’t have luggage on my ticket). This sounds really unreasonable that I can potentially be at the airport and the airline could charge me anything and I’d have no choice but to pay as I have a luggage with me. There’s no option to buy luggage online or via customer support. I’ve heard there are some court rulings regarding carry on luggage.  Is there any EU passenger rights that would allow me to at least know how much I’d be paying at the airport? Thanks.

Comment: Can you not buy the luggage option a this link? You need to log in with your booking information, otherwise I would check myself.... https://www.klm.at/en/information/baggage/extra-oversized-overweight-baggage#arrange-extra-checked-baggage

Comment: The prices are dynamic: it depends on the cargo they can sell to commercial companies. Note: AFAIK the rules tell that they may also refuse additional baggage. So, as Ozzy write: buy it in advance (you can add it also after you bought a ticket). It is much cheaper (normally). -- so it is like to ask a petrol station about the future prices of petrol -- Is it possible there is a maximum price, but because they can deny baggage at checkin, it is not much useful.

Comment: In Europe you always pay more for luggage at the check in desk, sometimes it's obscenely expensive.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you can even buy a ticket from the EU to Japan (so international long distance) without any checked luggage. Are you sure your ticket doesn't include one checked bag? I would assume one bag per passenger is always included, additional bags can then be restricted and possibly very expensive.

Comment: @quarague That is not at all unusual.

Comment: Without going into details about you booking, can't you find the prices you are looking for here? Here are fee tables for overweight, oversized and extra items both when booking in advance and at the airport: https://www.klm.com/information/legal/fees-paid-options

Comment: @quarague: it is common.. LH explained the reason: to be on top part of list when you compare flights.